# Removing item from BindingList does not refresh DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a DataGridView where there is a cell which is a DataGridViewComboCell.  Each DataGridViewComboCell is bound to a unique copy of a BindingList.  When I remove an item from the binding list the comboboxes remove the entry I had removed from the bindinglist.
However, if that value is selected it stays as the selected item in the cell.

I tried doing a datagridview.refresh(), but it still didn't help.  It is getting called from a tool strip menu item

```
  // _contractLists is List<BindingList<String>> which is the datasource for a datagridviewcombobox

List<String> removedList = new List<string>();
_contractSelForm.ShowDialog();
_contractSelForm.GetandClearRemovedContracts(ref removedList);

foreach (BindingList<String> contractList in _contractLists)
{
     // remove deleted favorites
    foreach (string contract_name in removedList)
    {
         contractList.Remove(contract_name);
    }
}  

dataGridView1.Refresh();
dataGridView1.EndEdit();
```

Comment: are you moving and or altering the binding in the correct event..? can you paste code that you are using..? also datagridview.Bind() or binding sounds like something to look at ..just a guess here without seeing your code

Comment: Can you show how you are binding the BindingLists to the combo box column?  Is the dataGridView1 in virtual mode?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to note/look at:

1) You shouldn't need to call EndEdit after Refresh. If it needs to be called, you should call it before Refresh.

2) If your comboboxes have a DropDownStyle of DropDown, then I this is expected behavior.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> If you set the DropDownStyle property to DropDown, you can type any value in the editable area of the ComboBox.

To change this, either change the DropDownStyle to DropDownList or manually clear the value in code after removing the items.